# Why would an application crash without leaving a crash dump?

Tags: windows-7, crash-dumps

I have an application that is crashing with a

> "The exception unknown software exception (0x4000000015) occurred in
>   the application at location 0x76d66109. Click on OK to terminate the
>   program"

but no crash dump is stored in the CrashDumps folder or any reference on the Reliability History.

How can I force a crash dump to be recorded?

Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit.

Comment: Did you try web search? Keyword: Windows Error Reporting.

Comment: Please see the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a 3rd party crash reporting tool like [CrashRpt](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/).